# Get WorkflowDesigner from a ModelItem

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am trying to create a custom IExpressionEditor. In order to new one up I need a WorkflowDesigner, All I have is the ModelItem representing my custom activity. Is it possible to access the WorkflowDesigner from a given ModelItem?

```
   List<ModelItem> variables = new List<ModelItem>();
   List<ModelItem> nameSpaces = new List<ModelItem>();

   // get the activity from the datacontext
   CustomActivityDesigner cad = this.DataContext as CustomActivityDesigner;
   // try to get the variables
   // look for variables collection cant seem to find them
   ModelProperty mp = cad.ModelItem.Properties["Variables"];

   if(mp != null && mp.PropertyType == typeof(Collection<Variable>))
   {
        mp.Collection.ToList().ForEach(i => variables.Add(i));
   }

   // get name spaces
   ModelProperty mp2 = cad.ModelItem.Properties["NameSpaces"];

   if(mp2 != null && mp2.PropertyType == typeof(Collection<NameSpace>))
   {
        mp2.Collection.ToList().ForEach(i => nameSpaces.Add(i));
   } 

   // finally need the WorkflowDesigner object
   WorkflowDesigner designer = Modelitem.Root....??? as WorkflowDesigner

   // now we have what we need we can create the IExpressionEditor
   CustomExpressionEditior ce = new CustomExpressionEditior(designer, variables, nameSpaces)
```

Comment: The ModelItem property is hierarchical so traversing this you can gain access to the root element of your workflow where defined variables can be found. ModelItem also has information about the type of the property so you can just select properties of certain type.

Comment: @kousic I can see that I can get the root item from my model item, but I cannot cast that to a WorkflowDesigner, nor do I see any properties to access the WorkflowDesigner object. I would like to get the Designer itself, then any variables defined in the scope of my custom activity, and any namespaces. Not finding much info online though.

Comment: Can you give me a sample code of your model item?

Comment: @kousic added sample code

Answer (score -1):

Following the [Using a Custom Expression Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/using-a-custom-expression-editor) as reference, it seems you should be able to create a **Custom Expression Service** (which will be creating the **Expression Editor** instances) and register it to the `Services` collection on the **WorkflowDesigner**.

Once it's registered in the **WorkflowDesigner**'s `Services` collection, you'll be able to:

- Get the editing context for the **ModelItem** by using [ModelItemExtensions.GetEditingContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activities.presentation.model.modelitemextensions.geteditingcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Activities_Presentation_Model_ModelItemExtensions_GetEditingContext_System_Activities_Presentation_Model_ModelItem_)
- Access the `Services` property of the returned [EditingContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activities.presentation.editingcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- Retrieve the **Custom Expression Service** you registered on the **WorkflowDesginer**

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, yes, I was able to grab the ServiceManager, variables and using statements all off the original modelItem and pass them through.